# SpringBoot 3 : LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, logback, slf4j, java-17

I'm using  springBootVersion = '3.0.2' and Java 17. Recently I have upgraded to springBoot 3 and Java 17. My build.gradle file is as below

```
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation (group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'){
        exclude group:  'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation (group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'){
        exclude group:  'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.9'
```

on ./gradlew clean build I'm getting the test failures with below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/4876720/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/88c40d8b4f33326f19a7d3c0aaf2c7e8721d4953/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory

StudentIntegrationTest > createStudent() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at Assert.java:713
```

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0 requires Logback 1.4.x. Why have you downgraded to 1.2.x?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson this was it for me too. But I couldn't find any documenation about it.

Comment: The upgrade is [listed in the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#third-party-library-upgrades). The reference documentation also lists all of Spring Boot's [default managed versions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions) and there's a [warning in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies.dependency-management-plugin.customizing) about the need to take care when overriding versions.